# Postfix - Mail only being received for one domain when configured to receive for several

Tags: postfix

I have postfix setup to receive mail for three domains example.net and example.com. I have this setup with aliases, with an info@ address for each domain both going to a local user, Jason. DNS is configured correctly and mail stuff is the same for both domains.

When I follow /var/log/mail.log with tail, I see absolutly no activity for example.com when testing by ending with my personal gmail account, but I do see activity for example.net.

Passage from mail.log when message is received to example.net:

```
Jul  3 18:54:25 mail postfix/smtpd[31644]: connect from mail-qt0-f181.google.com[209.85.216.181]
Jul  3 18:54:25 mail postfix/smtpd[31644]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-qt0-f181.google.com[209.85.216.181]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Jul  3 18:54:25 mail postfix/smtpd[31644]: 33009142FF0: client=mail-qt0-f181.google.com[209.85.216.181]
Jul  3 18:54:25 mail postfix/cleanup[31648]: 33009142FF0: message-id=<CAHsLCMmNCoZU0N0gFw28Yzm9HLpiCYOPyEwaBHq4ALQtSt2ssw@mail.gmail.com>
Jul  3 18:54:25 mail postfix/qmgr[31108]: 33009142FF0: from=<myemaily@gmail.com>, size=2590, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  3 18:54:25 mail postfix/smtpd[31644]: disconnect from mail-qt0-f181.google.com[209.85.216.181]
Jul  3 18:54:25 mail postfix/lmtp[31650]: 33009142FF0: to=<test@example.net>, orig_to=<info@example.net>, relay=example.net[/var/run/cyrus/socket/lmtp], delay=0.18, delays=0.15/0/0.01/0.01, dsn=2.1.5, status=sent (250 2.1.5 Ok SESSIONID=<cyrus-31651-1467586465-1>)
Jul  3 18:54:25 mail postfix/qmgr[31108]: 33009142FF0: removed
```

After a little while however, this also appears in the log:

```
Jul  3 19:02:51 mail postfix/qmgr[31108]: 8D183142FFD: from=<myemail@gmail.com>, size=2662, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  3 19:03:21 mail postfix/smtp[31706]: connect to localhost.localdomain[104.239.213.7]:25: Connection timed out
Jul  3 19:03:51 mail postfix/smtp[31706]: connect to localhost.localdomain[198.105.244.11]:25: Connection timed out
Jul  3 19:03:51 mail postfix/smtp[31706]: 8D183142FFD: to=<test@example.net>, orig_to=<info@example.net>, relay=none, delay=11281, delays=11221/0.01/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to localhost.localdomain[172.16.1.5]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Why is it trying to connect to localhost.localdomain, which seems to be resolving to a different IP on my network?

Output of postconf -n

```
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Mail/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/run/cyrus/socket/lmtp
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = example.net, example.com
myhostname = example.net
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = no
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Jul  3 19:03:51 [...] connect to **localhost.localdomain[172.16.1.5]**:25:
> Connection timed out)
> ```

Looks there is something strange here... localhost.localdomain should be left as 127.0.0.1 and not 172.16.1.5 as in your quote.

Try fixing this and see what changes.